# Simple regex to extract contents between square brackets in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, regex

I have a bunch of elements with names similar to "comp[1].Field" or "comp[3].AnotherField" where the index (1 or 3) changes.  I'm trying to extract the index from the name.

Right now I'm using:

```
var index = $(":input:last").attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];
```

but I don't feel like this is the best way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is actually a pretty good way to do it, but you should add some checking that ensures that match() actually returns an array (meaning the string was found) and not null, otherwise you'll get a type error.

example:

```
var index = $(":input:last").attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]/);
if (match) { index = match[1]; }
else { /* no match */ }
```

Comment: Another issue:  If $(":input:last") doesn't select anything, then .attr("name") will be undefined and .match will error out.

Comment: Also true... awareness is raised :)